# How items are placed next to each other

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wrote the following code with react-native for API

```
renderItem={({item})=><Text style={styles.item}> {item.title.rendered + item.excerpt.rendered } </Text>}
```

But I want the second item to be below the first item
Thank you for guiding me

Answer (score 2):

You just have to make a **View** and put your two elements in **Text** inside.

```
<View>
 <Text>{item.title.rendered </Text>
 <Text> {item.excerpt.rendered} </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: `<View style={{ flex: 9, backgroundColor: "#0a912c",borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,borderBottomRightRadius: 20, }} >
        
      <FlatList  
        data={data}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={()=> <View style={{borderWidth:1}}/>}
          renderItem={({item})=><Text style={styles.item}> {item.title.rendered + item.excerpt.rendered } </Text>} 
        />
      </View>`
I have tried this example before and I have not been successful
But the original code is like this
You can suggest another way

Comment: <View style={{ flex: 9, backgroundColor:... >
        
      <FlatList  
        data={data}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={()=> <View style={{borderWidth:1}}/>}
          renderItem={({item})=>
                               <>
                                <Text style={styles.item}> {item.title.rendered  } </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.item}> {item.excerpt.rendered } </Text>
                                </>    } 
        />
      </View>
Hello again
I have tried this code but is there a better way like the {/ n}